# How to serialize a class of objects as list of parameters without nesting

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Imagine I have a class with two different objects:

```
Object A contains string A1 and string A2  
Object B contains string B1 and string B2
```

If I were to serialize the class, the json would look something like this

```
{  
  "ObjectA" : {  
      "A1" : "foo",  
      "A2" : "bar"  
   },  
   "ObjectB": {  
      "B1" : "foo",  
      "B2" : "bar"  
   }  
}
```

However, this class structure is only supposed to help filling the class and doesn't represent the actual structure I need. It should look like this:

```
{  
    "A1": "foo",  
    "A2": "bar",  
    "B1": "foo",  
    "B2": "bar"  
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with Newtonsoft without going ahead and mapping A1,A2,B1 and B2 to another class?

Comment: Don't think so, why don't you map this to a class with the properties in the way you want to serialise first and then use Newtonsoft?

Comment: Mostly because the class doesnt just contains 2 strings, but round about a hundred. Sounds incredibly redundant to me to map it like that, which is why Im asking if there is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Merge` 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm

One way to go about it would be to extract `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` from your JObject then use Merge to get your required output

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(@"{  
  'ObjectA' : {  
      'A1' : 'foo',  
      'A2' : 'bar'  
   },  
   'ObjectB': {  
      'B1' : 'foo',  
      'B2' : 'bar'  
   }  
}  ");

JObject objectA = obj.SelectToken("ObjectA") as JObject;
JObject objectB = obj.SelectToken("ObjectB") as JObject;

objectA.Merge(objectB, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union });

string json = objectA.ToString();
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks.

Kind of unrelated, but maybe you know: Compared to mapping every single value to another class (assuming I have around 100 strings), is this method faster or slower?

Comment: I honestly could not answer if this was faster or slower. You'll have to perform a benchmark test for both. I could be wrong but for ~100 properties there should not be much performance difference.